# Elipse to a spheroid?

Tags: differential-geometry, parametrization, solid-of-revolution

I'm having a problem trying to prove that an elipse, given by
$$ \xi = \left\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : y = 0, \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1\right\}  $$
if we rotate to the z-axis is a spheroid given by
$$M = \left\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 :\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{a^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1 \right\}$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried going with the focal points but i'm really stuck

Comment: i know that if -c<z<c the section in M intersected by $z=z_0$ is a circumference with center $(0,0,z_0)$ and $$r = a^2
\sqrt{1-\frac{z_0^2}{c^2}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the initial $x$-axis as $r$. (Because now it is something like the (perpendicular) distance from the $z$-axis) Then you can use polar coordinates for the $xy$-plane.

$$ x = r \cos \theta \\
y = r \sin \theta$$

and perhaps a trigonometric identity to get the final answer that you seek.